# mongodump on Powershell with --query option : "error parsing query as extended json", "error parsing command line"

Tags: mongodb, powershell, mongodump

Trying to partially dump a collection with `mongodump`:

```
mongodump --uri "mongodb+srv://l:p@host/db" -o folder --collection collection --query '{ "meta.field": {"$gte": {"$date": "2023-01-01T00:00:00Z" }}}'
```

After searching on stackoverflow and mongo forums, I tried using `\` to escape the quotes, enclosing with triple quotes, enclosing with double quotes and using single quotes inside the query. Every time I get one of the errors mentioned in title.

Comment: Powershell uses backticks `\`` for escaping. However, I am surprised, that your command did not work.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Your comment surprised me so I did additional testing. I realised I wasn't using the latest Powershell version.
On v7.0.3, I had the aformentioned errors. With the latest version (7.3.5), above code works perfectly.

Comment: I added some details in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

#### Answer for powershell version < 7.3:

After some trial and error, I found this works (maybe this was mentioned somewhere on some forum but I couldn't find it):

```
mongodump --uri "mongodb+srv://l:p@host/db" -o folder --collection collection --query "{ `"meta.field`": {`"`$gte`": {`"`$date`": `"2023-01-01T00:00:00Z`" }}}"
```

Apparently, backticks are used as escape and not backslashes.

#### Edit

Wernfried's comment made be dig a bit more.
Since Powershell 7.3, arguments are passed differently : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/experimental-features?view=powershell-7.3#psnativecommandargumentpassing

So my initial command (in the question) now works in latest Powershell version.

Test arguments with PS 7.2.13:
[image: Screenshot of PS 7.2.13]

Test arguments with PS 7.3.6:
[image: Screenshot of PS 7.3.6]

Notice how quotes are handled differently.